C# Is it possible to send via SMTP with PERSONNAL OUTLOOK account via OAUTH2?
With the recent rollout of Microsoft and Google (on Sept. 30th, 2024) to disable the Basic Authentication, my third party app to send email isn't working anymore with personnal Outlook Account aka. xyz@outlook.com for exemple.
Any tips & tricks would be appreciated.
It is working with professional email such as xyz@domain.com
I went throught all the process of:

Becoming partner with Microsoft
Created an app on Microsoft Entra ID
Validate the MPN ID for my app
Setup all the API autorisations
I even invited the personnal Outlook Account to the users

I've been working 3-4 days straight on that problem, reading multiple ressources online.
I've verified my access token on jwt.ms. Allthought on the personnal account, the amr claim-type is still giving me pwd even tho I deactivated everything but MFA on that account
Also my appidacr claim-type is 0 : Indicates how the client was authenticated. For a public client, the value is "0". If client ID and client secret are used, the value is "1". If a client certificate was used for authentication, the value is "2". (I guess it relates with):
 var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
.Create(clientId)
.WithTenantId(tenantId)
.WithRedirectUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient")
.Build();

